# How to send binary file via HTTP?

Tags: java, android, http, http-headers

I am working on an Android application that establish a mini-http server to send kind of files to clients. Clients send the request and this application respond with a regular http response (so it contains header and the file content).

I have a piece of code that works with text files.

```
os = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

    String filename = "index.html";
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/FileShare/",filename);

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {...}

os.print("HTTP/1.0 200" + "\r\n");
os.print("Content type: " + getMimeType(filename) + "\r\n");
os.print("Content length: " + text.length() + "\r\n");
os.print("\r\n");
os.print(text + "\r\n");
os.flush();
socket.close();
```

So my question is how to put binary data to the http content?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You started off with an output stream from the socket -- I think if you hold onto that reference (instead of directly wrapping it in the PrintWriter), I think you should be able to write the headers using `os.print` as you've done, then flush the writer, and then write the rest of the payload do the output stream directly. I'm not sure about that, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Google for multipart. And dont use readers and readline(). Its pretty standard what you want so you will find many examples.